# Python - Show one image from an image array

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, pytorch, dcgan

I'm going through this tutorial on pytorch. https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/dcgan_faces_tutorial.html
And I've been able to show real images next to the fake ones that I have generated.

```
# Grab a batch of real images from the dataloader
real_batch = next(iter(dataloader))

# Plot the real images
plt.figure(figsize=(15,15))
plt.subplot(1,2,1)
plt.axis("off")
plt.title("Real Images")
plt.imshow(np.transpose(vutils.make_grid(real_batch[0].to(device)[:64], padding=5, normalize=True).cpu(),(1,2,0)))

# Plot the fake images from the last epoch
plt.subplot(1,2,2)
plt.axis("off")
plt.title("Fake Images")
plt.imshow(np.transpose(img_list[-1],(1,2,0)))
plt.show()
```

Which from my dataset results in this:
[image]

I was wondering how I can show one image from the fake images generated. I also want to show it as a 512 X 512 image if possible.

Edit:
The img_list[-1].shape is torch.Size([3, 530, 530]).

Edit2: [image]

This part of the training shows that img_list is a list of images with each image being a group of sub-images (not being able to separate them). Is there a way I can edit this to make img_list an image of each fake image generated?

Comment: What is the shape of `img_list[-1]`? Do you have the definition of `img_list`?

Comment: I know that img_list goes up to 7 on the first index, but I'm not sure on the following indices. I used 7 epochs instead of the 5 on the tutorial, if that makes a difference.

Comment: Ok, could you maybe output `img_list[-1].shape`?

Comment: torch.Size([3, 530, 530])

Comment: I'm guessing this already corresponds to an image grid, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I wanted:

```
noise = torch.randn(1, nz, 1, 1, device=device)
with torch.no_grad():
    newfake = netG(noise).detach().cpu()

plt.axis("off")
plt.imshow(np.transpose(newfake[0],(1,2,0)))
plt.show()
```

As it generates a new image, with a new noise. The img_list was combining the generated images into one image.
However, this code still only generates 64 by 64 pixel images.